# Unit testing with mocks and reflections in PHPUnit

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm need to test protected method `testMethod` of class which uses some another method `mockMethod`. So I'm writing:

```
$class = $this->getMockBuilder('TestingClassName')
    ->setMethods(['mockMethod'])
    ->getMock();

$class->expects($this->any())
    ->method('mockMethod')
    ->will($this->returnValue('Hey!'));

$reflection = new \ReflectionObject($class);
    $method = $reflection->getMethod('testMethod');
    $method->setAccessible(true);

$result = $method->invokeArgs($class, $paramsArray);
```

But when method `mockMethod` invokes inside of `testMethod` it becomes like not mocked. It's protected method too and if I invoke it with another `ReflectionMethod` - I will give 'Hey!' from it.

Comment: `$method->invokeArgs($class, $paramsArray)` -- why do you pass a mock object to the `testMethod`? Are you trying to force a context for that `ReflectionMethod`? Because I don't think invokeArgs can do that.

Comment: It's strange - it should work. Are you sure that mockMethod is not private nor final? I've repeat your code and it works for me. I'd like to add - there is a practice which is considered as a good one which tells that you should not test protected or private methods. A class should be tested through it interface, therefore you should test protected/private methods through public ones.

Comment: It's much more easier to refactor your code and extract the protected methods functionality to a new class. Then you use a mock of that class instead of the real instance, when testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the inner method was `private`, not `protected`.